# python ordereddict when the key is a "numeric string"

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting, ordereddictionary

i have an unordered dict with numeric keys but in string format, and i want to get a ordered dict (by the numeric key):

```
my_dict__ = {'3': 6, '1': 8, '11': 2, '7': 55, '22': 1}
my_dict_ = {}
for key, value in my_dict__.items():
    my_dict_[int(key)] = value
my_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict_.items()))
```

how can i simply this?

(The result, can have the key as int or string)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
my_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict__.items(), key=lambda x:int(x[0])))
# OrderedDict([('1', 8), ('3', 6), ('7', 55), ('11', 2), ('22', 1)])
```

Comment: @fj123x do you have python 2 or python 3?

Answer (score 3):

you can also create the int dict directly with something like:

```
my_dict = OrderedDict(sorted((int(key), value) for key, value in my_dict__.items()))
```

this gives you:

```
OrderedDict([(1, 8), (3, 6), (7, 55), (11, 2), (22, 1)])
```

if that's more useful as an end result.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> my_dict__ = {'3': 6, '1': 8, '11': 2, '7': 55, '22': 1}
>>> keylist = sorted(my_dict__.keys(), key=lambda x: int(x))
>>> my_dict = OrderedDict(((k, my_dict__[k]) for k in keylist))
>>> my_dict
OrderedDict([('1', 8), ('3', 6), ('7', 55), ('11', 2), ('22', 1)])
```

It's pretty much the same thing as Roman's answer though so I don't know why his answer wouldn't work for you.